# How to view Pokémon Bank subscription info?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I honestly can't believe I even need to be here to ask this, I figured viewing subscription info is something most subscription services had got down without a problem years and years ago.

Yet here I am.

How the heck do I view subscription info for Pokémon Bank? I've logged into Pokémon.com, been on Pokémon Global Link and I've checked the Pokémon Bank site too. I can't find this info anywhere.

I know how many days I have left, I can see on my DS, but I want to see other info about it, that is - if it's renewed, if my card is set up for it, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Although I can find nothing to back this up at the moment, I was under the impression that it doesn't automatically renew, and thus your card wouldn't be "set up for it" (which would be odd anyway, as payment is done through funds deposited in the Nintendo e-Shop), and thus technically it would not be a "subscription" and therefore not need subscription info.

Comment: As possible support for my interpretation, note that questions 4 and 5 on [the FAQ](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/faq/) refer to annual passes expiring without any implications of a new one being automatically purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Pokemon Bank is not a subscription service, but uses licenses that expire after one year.

You buy a license and the software displays to you how many days are left. After that period has passed, you will no longer be able to use the software until you purchase a new 1-year-license through the software (or technically through the e-Shop, but that option is only available through Bank itself) using e-Shop funds, which you can top-up with different payment methods at any time including right when you want to buy something and don't have sufficient funds in your account. That's entirely independant on which software (or license) you're buying with those funds, though.